# document.getElementById() != null is not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, razor

I have the following script inside my Razor view :-

```
if (document.getElementById("currentdate") != null && document.getElementById("currenttime") != null) {
        document.getElementById("currentdate").innerHTML = EMBEDformatAMPM();
```

what i am doing is the folloiwng :-

- Since the `currentdate & currenttime` are only displayed if the user is authenticated . so if the element is not displayed the `getElementById.innerHTML` will raise a reference exception. so that why i decide to check if these elements exists or not before setting their `.innerHTML`. 
  My checking is working well on IE and chrome, while on firefox the current date and time will not be displayed even if the currentdate and currenttime DOM elements exists

.. can anyone advice please ?

**Edit**
Here is the generated HTML:-

```
<section id="login" class="navbar-search pull-right">
  <span class="username customTopNavText " style=" display:block; ">
      [<a href="/tms/Account/LogOff/" style="color:white"> Logout </a>]
      <i class="icon-user"></i> <strong >   </strong>
  </span>
  <div  class="customTopNavText" id="currentdate"></div>
  <div  class="customTopNavText" id="currenttime" ></div>   
      <form class="customSearch"method="GET" action="/tms/Home/Search">
          <input  class="push-up-button searchmargin" placeholder="Search by tag.." name="searchTerm2" data-autocomplete-source= "/tms/Home/AutoComplete" type="text" style="margin-top:8px"/><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" />
      </form>
</section>

<div class="top-nav nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="customTitle" style= "color:#f99406">TMS - Staging  </li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

where both the currentdate & currenttime are there , but their HTML is not being set using the following script:-

```
    var el = document.getElementById('currentdate');
    if (el != null) {
        //if (document.getElementById("currentdate") != null && document.getElementById("currenttime") != null) {
        document.getElementById("currentdate").innerHTML = EMBEDformatAMPM();
        var myVar = setInterval(function () { myTimer() }, 30000);

        function myTimer() {
            document.getElementById("currentdate").innerHTML = EMBEDformatAMPM();
        }
        function EMBEDformatAMPM() {
            var d = new Date(),
                minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
                hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
                ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
                months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
            return days[d.getDay()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear();
        }
        document.getElementById("currenttime").innerHTML = EMBEDformatAMPM2();

        var myVar2 = setInterval(function () { myTimer2() }, 30000);
        function myTimer2() {
            document.getElementById("currenttime").innerHTML = EMBEDformatAMPM2();
        }
        function EMBEDformatAMPM2() {
            var d = new Date(),
                minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
                hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
                ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
                months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
            return hours + ':' + minutes;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information, preferably a complete example that reproduces the problem in FF.

Comment: if you are using jQuery you can check if it exists by doing `$("#currentdate").length`

Comment: Using `getElementById` twice to get the same element is overkill. Better use it only once and save the returned value in a variable. Moreover, since `getElementById` returns only objects, you can skip comparison with `null` and just let it be coerced to boolean.

Comment: @Oriol why it is overkill ? and i am not using it to get the same element ..

Comment: @Pete so do u mean that using != null is not the right approach to check if the element exists or not ?

Comment: He means you could do: `var el = document.getElementById('currentdate'); if (el != null) { el.innerHTML = EMBEDformatAMPM(); }` Also the way you are checking if the element is there is fine. `getElementById` either returns an `Element` object or `null`.

Comment: @FelixKling the problem is that Firefox will not bypass the if statement check even if the two DOM elements are not null ...

Comment: I understand the problem, I just cannot imagine that such a simple thing as an `if` statement works differently in FF than in Chrome. Hence I believe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the ID 'currentdate' or 'curenttime'?  Firefox is often more strict about it than others (you may even have an error on your console about it).

Comment: @johnG, I was just giving you another way of checking if an element exists as you have tagged your post with jQuery but as far as I can see your code should work in firefox too: http://jsfiddle.net/LFTcf/.  Are you sure you are running the statement after your dom has finished loading

Comment: @RobH using var el = document.getElementById('currentdate'); if (el != null) { el.innerHTML = EMBEDformatAMPM(); } will not solve the problem , as on firefox the data & time will never be displayed ..

Comment: @SeanVieira it wouldn't matter if there were multiple - all browsers would just pick up the first element with that id it came to and discard any others

Comment: @SeanVieira no only one element

Comment: Is it an ID case sensitivity issue? They should be case sensitive, but some browsers search without regard to case. What are the IDs in the DOM? (Be careful about the case)

Comment: @JuanMendes i am using the same ID case all are lower case..

Comment: @JohnG - I know, I was explaining Oriol's comment. By storing the result in a varible you don't have to get by id again within the if block

Comment: @johnG Show your HTML exactly as it is

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @JuanMendes can you check my Edit , i have provided the related HTML..

Comment: @RobH no error on the console , otherwise i would have posted them ,,,

Comment: Save yourself some code `var myVar = setInterval(function () { myTimer() }, 30000);` could be `var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 30000);`. Also, have you tried debugging and stopping at that `if` condition?

Comment: Try without the `!= null`. Just use `if (document.getElementById("currentdate") && document.getElementById("currenttime"))`

Comment: @Gil nothing will chnage if i use if (document.getElementById("currentdate") && document.getElementById("currenttime")) !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox generally chokes with hoisting function declarations in blocks... You can try a simple example yourself:

```
if (true) {
    execute();
    function execute() { alert("worked"); } 
}
```

The above works in Chrome and IE but doesn't in FF (although there is an error). Try putting the declaration of `EMBEDformatAMPM` outside of your if:

```
function EMBEDformatAMPM() {
    var d = new Date(),
        minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
        hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
        ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
        months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    return days[d.getDay()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear();
}

var el = document.getElementById('currentdate'); 
if (el != null) {       
        el.innerHTML = EMBEDformatAMPM();
}
```

I may be a being slightly unfair to say that FF chokes - according to the spec the only thing allowed within a block are statements and a function declaration is not a statement.

You may also want to head over to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) as there are several things in your code that could be improved.

### Edit (replying to comments)

It's not a bug with Firefox as what you are doing is not technically allowed according to the specification. Chrome and IE are being more permissive by making a good guess at what you want but there's no guarantee that it will work in future versions.

As to improvements to your code, check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkfX4/1/)

```
// wrap in IIFE to avoid polluting global namespace.
(function () {
   // declare all our variables at the top of the function
    var currentDate = document.getElementById('currentdate'),
       currentTime = document.getElementById('currenttime'),
       updateTime,
       getFormattedDate,
       getFormattedTime;

    // Give functions names that make their purpose clear
    getFormattedDate = function() {
            var d = new Date(),
                months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
            return days[d.getDay()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear();       
    };
    getFormattedTime = function () {
            var d = new Date(),
                minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
                hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getHours() : d.getHours();
            return hours + ':' + minutes;
    };

    // This function updates the time and then 
    // sets a timeout to execute again after 3 seconds.
    updateTime = function () {
        if (currentTime !== null && currentDate !== null) {
            currentTime.innerHTML = getFormattedTime();
            currentDate.innerHTML = getFormattedDate();
        }
        window.setTimeout(updateTime, 3000);
    };
    // Start it off.
    updateTime();
}());
```

Comment: yes it worked well, so can i consider my problem as a bug in FF ? or i should not be having such a function inside an If statemnt ?

Comment: also if you could mentione which area i can improve in my code ?

Comment: I will update in about 30 mins but it's not a bug in ff.